# Calculation off of a calculated field in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a list of records from which I need to calculate a new field - I'll call it "calculation"
Each row depends upon the previous rows number. The first index of each ID's "calculation" field is provided. See below for a screenshot from excel displaying what I'm trying to do, but for millions of records, partitioned by ID

[image: excel screenshot displaying what I want to do]

My query below breaks, since calculation does not yet exist

```
select ID, transaction, transaction-lag(calculation) over (partition by ID) as calculation from db
```

Is this possible in Vertica?

Comment: Your results depend on the ordering of the rows.  What column specifies that ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results depend on the ordering of the data.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If I assume you have a column that specifies the ordering, then you want something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (first_value(calculation) over (partition by id order by <ordering col>) -
        sum(transaction) over (partition by id order by <ordering col>)
       ) as calculation
from t
```

Comment: Thank you - yes I have a row_num column, sorry I should have specified.

Your solution helps, but the calculations are not all done off of the first value, rather the previous value. So in my excel screenshot cell C4 would be B4-C3. Is there still a way to calculate this?

Comment: @tnerbusas . . . They are two ways of looking at the same calculation.  The cumulative sum does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I need to edit this, after all.
I tried @Gordon Linoff 's approach, to no avail, with the example data I supply in this post.

I would use the `LAG()` OLAP function. I also use Vertica's *named window* clause for readability ( `WINDOW w AS ()` ) .

In addition to that: Your Excel sheet calculates in an iterative manner. Your `C4` is calculated out of `B4 - C3` , while `C3` is calculated, in turn, as you show, as `B3 - C2`.
So all I can do is to nest two very similar queries:

In the first query from your input, which I name `fillonce`, I manage to calculate your `C3`, as `IFNULL(calculation,transaction-LAG(calculation) OVER(w))` (using the named window `w`), meaning: If `calculation` is not null, use `calculation`, else subtract `calculation` of the previous row ( `LAG()`) from `transaction` of this row.

The outmost query selects from `fillonce`, and does the same. I added `calc_org` as the original calculation number, for reference.

Your input:

```
WITH
-- your input enhanced by row_num and expected result ...
input(id,row_num,transaction,calculation,expected) AS (
          SELECT 123,1, 3.75,1.45,1.45
UNION ALL SELECT 123,2, 4.55,NULL,3.10
UNION ALL SELECT 123,3, 4.13,NULL,1.03
UNION ALL SELECT 456,1,12.3 ,3.22,3.22
UNION ALL SELECT 456,2, 2.22,NULL,-1
)
```

-- End of your input ...

-- what follows now is a first iteration of filling missing values

-- note the named window clause  - `WINDOW w AS (....)`

```
,
fillonce AS (
  SELECT 
    id
  , row_num
  , transaction
  , calculation AS calc_org
  ,
      FIRST_VALUE(calculation) OVER(w) 
    - SUM(transaction) OVER(w) 
    AS calculation
  , expected
  FROM input
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY row_num)
)
```

-- which would return, in `fillonce`:

```
id  | row_num | transaction | calc_org | calculation | expected 
----+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------
123 |       1 |        3.75 |     1.45 |        1.45 |     1.45
123 |       2 |        4.55 |     NULL |        3.10 |     3.10
123 |       3 |        4.13 |     NULL |        NULL |     1.03
456 |       1 |       12.30 |     3.22 |        3.22 |     3.22
456 |       2 |        2.22 |     NULL |       -1.00 |    -1.00
```

-- and the final select, where I fill the last value that is still NULL:

```
SELECT 
  id
, row_num
, transaction
, calculation AS calc_org
, IFNULL(calculation,transaction - LAG(calculation) OVER(w)) AS calculation
, expected
FROM fillonce
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY row_num)
;
```

-- which finally returns:

```
 id  | row_num | transaction | calc_org | calculation | expected
-----+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+---------
 123 |       1 |        3.75 |     1.45 |        1.45 |     1.45
 123 |       2 |        4.55 |     3.10 |        3.10 |     3.10
 123 |       3 |        4.13 |     NULL |        1.03 |     1.03
 456 |       1 |       12.30 |     3.22 |        3.22 |     3.22
 456 |       2 |        2.22 |    -1.00 |       -1.00 |    -1.00
```